# Are weapons and mods permanently missable?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 2, there was a chance that if you didn't pick up a weapon/upgrade during certain missions, then you could miss them entirely if you completed the mission without picking them up.

However, they also had the functionality where if you missed picking up a weapon in one part of the level, you could get a chance to pick it up in another part of the level before the mission ended.

Does this work the same way in Mass Effect 3? Or have they changed it so you'll be able to pick up weapons/mods in later missions if you missed them at your first opportunity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, missed items will be available in shops. If you've missed more than one item of a particular type, the next item will only be unlocked after you bought the previous one, not necessarily in the same shop. You can check the available items in the shuttle bay.

Comment: So basically, the main advantage of finding them "in the field" now is that you don't have to pay for them later? How soon will they be available in the shops?

Comment: Yes, that's right. They will be available immediately after completing the mission.